# Update / Save model date value directly from template?

Tags: python, django

I am still quite inexperienced in Django and I was wondering if it would be at all possible to update/save today's date in my database directly from the template?

I have a Django-filter filterView (listView) that shows the list of people that are in my department which I currently have in my database. And I would like to update a datetime value (when the people have last been visited) to today's date by clicking on a <\a> link that shows in the list. That way I don't have to setup an update view just to update when I've last visited the coworkers. Is something like this even possible?

I did try to implement a function in my models.py with the @property tag but when I refresh the webpage, or visit the page it automatically updates it without having to click on the link.

Edit: Here is the code:

```
# models.py
@property
def update_visit_date(self):
    self.last_visit = timezone.make_aware(datetime.datetime.today())
    super(Directory, self).save()
    return reverse('directory_list')

# snippet from my template directory_list.html
  {% for contact in items %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ contact.first_name }}</td>
      <td>{{ contact.last_name }}</td>
      <th><a href="{{ contact.get_absolute_url }}">{{ contact.email_address }}</a></th>
      <td>{{ contact.phone_number_1 }}</td>
      <td>{{ contact.get_department_display }}</td>
      <td>{{ contact.room_number }}</td>
      {% if contact.is_past_due == 'no_visit_performed' %}
        <td class="info">{{ contact.last_visit }}<a href="{{
contact.update_visit_date }}"> {% bootstrap_icon "plus-sign" %}</a></td>
      {% elif contact.is_past_due == 'visit_good' %}
        <td class="success">{{ contact.last_visit }}<a href="{{ 
contact.update_visit_date }}"> {% bootstrap_icon "plus-sign" %}</a></td>
      {% elif contact.is_past_due == 'visit_old' %}
        <td class="warning">{{ contact.last_visit }}<a href="{{ 
contact.update_visit_date }}"> {% bootstrap_icon "plus-sign" %}</a></td>
      {% elif contact.is_past_due == 'need_visit' %}
        <td class="danger">{{ contact.last_visit }}<a href="{{ 
contact.update_visit_date }}"> {% bootstrap_icon "plus-sign" %}</a></td>
      {% endif %}
    </tr>
  {% empty %}
```

Is this something that is possible, the performing a CRUD from a template link? Or am I going about this the wrong way? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!

EDIT:  Found a resolve.  What I ended up doing is I created a function based view that performed the CRUD.  Here is the code:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
def last_visit_view(request, pk):
    last_visit_obj = Directory.objects.filter(pk=pk)
    if last_visit_obj:
        last_visit_obj = last_visit_obj[0]
        last_visit_obj.last_visit = datetime.now()
        last_visit_obj.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('directory_list'))
```

My template url calls this function and it works great.  Now I need to see how I am able to keep my filtered results on the HttpResponseRedirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There always has to be a view to linked to the template. You need to hook up a view to carry out a CRUD action like what you're trying to do.

If you won't like to reload the template, you can use an AJAX request to the view to perform the CRUD action.

In your shared snippet, you created a model property that updates `last_visit`.

Note that this model's `last_visit` is updated when template interpolation is carried out and not when the link is clicked which I suppose isn't the behavior you're gunning for.

```
<a href="{{ contact.update_visit_date }}">
```

Comment: Thank you for you comment, because of it I was able to find a resolve.  What I eneded up doing was creating a function based view that performed the CRUD.  I will edit me question with code.